# p:message Not displaying in p:dialog

Tags: jsf, user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces

In p:dialog `addCommodityDlg` i have some text fields. I'm trying to show validation message for those fields.
But did't achieve it.

Code:

```
    <p:dialog id="addCommodityDlg" widgetVar="createCommodity"
                   width="625" height="400" modal="true" header="Add Items">  

          <h:panelGrid columns="3">
             <h:outputLabel value="ID" />
             <h:inputText value="#{deliveryOderController.selectedCommodity.commodityId}" 
                          id="commodityIdTF" required="true"  />
             <p:message for="commodityIdTF"/>

             <h:outputLabel value="Name"/>
             <h:inputText value="#{deliveryOderController.selectedCommodity.commodityName}"
                          id="commodityNameTF"/>                                                                                   
             <p:message for="commodityNameTF"/>
          </h:panelGrid>

          <p:commandLink  styleClass="saveButtonLnk"  
                          actionListener="#{deliveryOderController.saveItems}" 
                          update=":createDOForm:transportUnitPnl">                    
         </p:commandLink>
  </p:dialog>
```

How Can i display Validation message in p:dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give those `p:message` components an id and put them in the update of your `p:commandLink`:

```
<p:dialog id="addCommodityDlg" widgetVar="createCommodity"
                   width="625" height="400" modal="true" header="Add Items">  
             ...
             <p:message id="commodityIdTFMessage" for="commodityIdTF"/>
             ...
             <p:message for="commodityNameTF" id="commodityNameTFMessage" />
          </h:panelGrid>
          <p:commandLink  styleClass="saveButtonLnk"  
                          actionListener="#{deliveryOderController.saveItems}" 
                          update=":createDOForm:transportUnitPnl commodityIdTFMessage commodityNameTFMessage">                    
         </p:commandLink>
</p:dialog>
```